# Debian squeeze keyboard and touchpad not working / detected on laptop

Tags: laptop, keyboard, debian, debian-squeeze, gdm

They work before gdm3 starts. a connected mouse also stops working, but functions after removal and re-plug. no xorg.conf.

log doesn't show any loading of drivers for kbd/touchpad

```
[    33.783] 
X.Org X Server 1.10.4
Release Date: 2011-08-19
[    33.783] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    33.783] Build Operating System: Linux 3.0.0-1-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[    33.783] Current Operating System: Linux sus 3.2.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Mar 25 10:33:35 UTC 2012 x86_64
[    33.783] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 root=UUID=8686f840-d165-4d1e-b995-2ebbd94aa3d2 ro quiet
[    33.783] Build Date: 28 August 2011  09:39:43PM
[    33.783] xorg-server 2:1.10.4-1~bpo60+1 (Cyril Brulebois <kibi@debian.org>) 
[    33.783] Current version of pixman: 0.16.4
[    33.783]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    33.783] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    33.783] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Mar 28 09:34:04 2012
[    33.837] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    33.936] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    33.936] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    33.936] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    33.936] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    33.936] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    33.936] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    33.936] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    34.164] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    34.164]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    34.226] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType,
    built-ins
[    34.226] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    34.226] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    34.226] (II) Loader magic: 0x7d3ae0
[    34.226] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    34.226]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    34.226]    X.Org Video Driver: 10.0
[    34.226]    X.Org XInput driver : 12.2
[    34.226]    X.Org Server Extension : 5.0
[    34.227] (--) PCI:*(0:1:5:0) 1002:9712:103c:1661 rev 0, Mem @ 0xd0000000/268435456, 0xf1400000/65536, 0xf1300000/1048576, I/O @ 0x00008000/256
[    34.227] (--) PCI: (0:2:0:0) 1002:6760:103c:1661 rev 0, Mem @ 0xe0000000/268435456, 0xf0300000/131072, I/O @ 0x00004000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    34.227] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[    34.227] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[    34.249] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[    34.277] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.277]    compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    34.277]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    34.277]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[    34.277] (II) Loading extension SELinux
[    34.277] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    34.277] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    34.277] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[    34.277] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[    34.277] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[    34.277] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    34.277] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[    34.277] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[    34.277] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[    34.299] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.299]    compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    34.299]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    34.299]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[    34.299] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    34.299] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    34.299] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    34.477] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.477]    compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    34.477]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[    34.477] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    34.477] (II) Loading extension GLX
[    34.477] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[    34.478] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[    34.481] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.481]    compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.13.0
[    34.481]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    34.481]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[    34.481] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[    34.481] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[    34.481] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[    34.512] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.512]    compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    34.512]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[    34.512] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[    34.512] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    34.512] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[    34.515] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.515]    compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.2.0
[    34.515]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[    34.515] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[    34.515] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 0
[    34.515] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 1
[    34.515] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[    34.515] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    34.515] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[    34.706] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[    34.724] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.724]    compiled for 1.10.3, module version = 6.14.2
[    34.724]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    34.724]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[    34.724] (II) LoadModule: "radeon"
[    34.725] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
[    34.923] (II) Module radeon: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.923]    compiled for 1.10.3, module version = 6.14.2
[    34.923]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    34.923]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[    34.945] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    34.945] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    34.988] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.988]    compiled for 1.10.3, module version = 2.3.0
[    34.988]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    34.988]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[    34.988] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    34.988] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    35.020] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.020]    compiled for 1.10.3, module version = 0.4.2
[    35.020]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[    35.020] (II) RADEON: Driver for ATI Radeon chipsets:
<snip>
[    35.023] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    35.023] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    35.023] (++) using VT number 7
[    35.033] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
[    35.033] (II) [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
[    35.033] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    35.034] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    35.034] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    35.034] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    35.034] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    35.185] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.185]    compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 0.0.2
[    35.185]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[    35.288] (II) RADEON(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    35.288] (==) RADEON(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    35.288] (II) RADEON(0): Pixel depth = 24 bits stored in 4 bytes (32 bpp pixmaps)
[    35.288] (==) RADEON(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    35.288] (==) RADEON(0): RGB weight 888
[    35.288] (II) RADEON(0): Using 8 bits per RGB (8 bit DAC)
[    35.288] (--) RADEON(0): Chipset: "ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4200" (ChipID = 0x9712)
[    35.288] (II) RADEON(0): PCI card detected
[    35.288] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[    35.288] drmOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[    35.288] drmOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID pci:0000:01:05.0
[    35.288] drmOpenDevice: node name is /dev/dri/card0
[    35.288] drmOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
[    35.288] drmOpenByBusid: drmOpenMinor returns 9
[    35.288] drmOpenByBusid: drmGetBusid reports pci:0000:01:05.0
[    35.288] (II) Loading sub module "exa"
[    35.288] (II) LoadModule: "exa"
[    35.288] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libexa.so
[    35.335] (II) Module exa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.335]    compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 2.5.0
[    35.335]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[    35.335] (II) RADEON(0): KMS Color Tiling: disabled
[    35.335] (II) RADEON(0): KMS Pageflipping: enabled
[    35.335] (II) RADEON(0): SwapBuffers wait for vsync: enabled
[    35.360] (II) RADEON(0): Output VGA-0 has no monitor section
[    35.360] (II) RADEON(0): Output LVDS has no monitor section
[    35.364] (II) RADEON(0): Output HDMI-0 has no monitor section
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): EDID for output VGA-0
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): EDID for output LVDS
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): Manufacturer: LGD  Model: 2ac  Serial#: 0
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): Year: 2010  Week: 0
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): Digital Display Input
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 34  vert.: 19
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): Gamma: 2.20
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): No DPMS capabilities specified
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): redX: 0.616 redY: 0.371   greenX: 0.355 greenY: 0.606
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): blueX: 0.152 blueY: 0.100   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): Supported detailed timing:
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): clock: 69.3 MHz   Image Size:  344 x 194 mm
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): h_active: 1366  h_sync: 1398  h_sync_end 1430 h_blank_end 1486 h_border: 0
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): v_active: 768  v_sync: 770  v_sync_end 774 v_blanking: 782 v_border: 0
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0):  LG Display
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0):  LP156WH2-TLQB
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): EDID (in hex):
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0):    00ffffffffffff0030e4ac0200000000
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0):    00140103802213780ac1259d5f5b9b27
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0):    19505400000001010101010101010101
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0):    010101010101121b567850000e302020
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0):    240058c2100000190000000000000000
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0):    00000000000000000000000000fe004c
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0):    4720446973706c61790a2020000000fe
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0):    004c503135365748322d544c514200c1
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): Printing probed modes for output LVDS
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1366x768"x59.6   69.30  1366 1398 1430 1486  768 770 774 782 -hsync -vsync (46.6 kHz)
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x720"x59.9   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync (44.8 kHz)
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1152x768"x59.8   71.75  1152 1216 1328 1504  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync (47.7 kHz)
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x59.9   63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync (47.8 kHz)
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x59.9   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync (37.4 kHz)
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "848x480"x59.7   31.50  848 872 952 1056  480 483 493 500 -hsync +vsync (29.8 kHz)
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "720x480"x59.7   26.75  720 744 808 896  480 483 493 500 -hsync +vsync (29.9 kHz)
[    35.388] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x59.4   23.75  640 664 720 800  480 483 487 500 -hsync +vsync (29.7 kHz)
[    35.392] (II) RADEON(0): EDID for output HDMI-0
[    35.392] (II) RADEON(0): Output VGA-0 disconnected
[    35.392] (II) RADEON(0): Output LVDS connected
[    35.392] (II) RADEON(0): Output HDMI-0 disconnected
[    35.392] (II) RADEON(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[    35.392] (II) RADEON(0): Output LVDS using initial mode 1366x768
[    35.392] (II) RADEON(0): Using default gamma of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) unless otherwise stated.
[    35.392] (II) RADEON(0): mem size init: gart size :1fdff000 vram size: s:10000000 visible:fba0000
[    35.392] (II) RADEON(0): EXA: Driver will allow EXA pixmaps in VRAM
[    35.392] (==) RADEON(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    35.392] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    35.392] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    35.392] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    35.492] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.492]    compiled for 1.10.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    35.492]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    35.492] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    35.492] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    35.492] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    35.492] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    35.492] (II) Unloading vesa
[    35.492] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[    35.492] (II) Unloading fbdev
[    35.492] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    35.492] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[    35.492] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    35.492] (II) RADEON(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    35.492] (II) RADEON(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: r600
[    35.492] (II) RADEON(0): Front buffer size: 4224K
[    35.492] (II) RADEON(0): VRAM usage limit set to 228096K
[    35.615] (==) RADEON(0): Backing store disabled
[    35.615] (II) RADEON(0): Direct rendering enabled
[    35.658] (II) RADEON(0): Setting EXA maxPitchBytes
[    35.658] (II) EXA(0): Driver allocated offscreen pixmaps
[    35.658] (II) EXA(0): Driver registered support for the following operations:
[    35.658] (II)         Solid
[    35.658] (II)         Copy
[    35.658] (II)         Composite (RENDER acceleration)
[    35.658] (II)         UploadToScreen
[    35.658] (II)         DownloadFromScreen
[    35.687] (II) RADEON(0): Acceleration enabled
[    35.687] (==) RADEON(0): DPMS enabled
[    35.687] (==) RADEON(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    35.721] (II) RADEON(0): Set up textured video
[    35.721] (II) RADEON(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[    35.721] (--) RandR disabled
[    35.721] (II) Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[    35.721] (II) Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[    35.721] (II) Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[    35.721] (II) Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[    35.721] (II) Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[    35.721] (II) Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    35.721] (II) Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[    35.721] (II) Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[    35.721] (II) Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[    35.721] (II) Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[    35.721] (II) Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[    35.721] (II) Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[    35.721] (II) Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[    35.721] (II) Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[    35.721] (II) Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[    35.721] (II) Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[    35.721] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    35.982] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[    35.982] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_INTEL_swap_event
[    35.982] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control and GLX_MESA_swap_control
[    35.982] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_make_current_read
[    35.982] (II) AIGLX: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap backed by buffer objects
[    35.982] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized /usr/lib/dri/r600_dri.so
[    35.982] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[    35.999] (II) RADEON(0): Setting screen physical size to 361 x 203
[    43.896] (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 684
[    43.896] (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    43.896] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   69.30  1366 1398 1430 1486  768 770 774 782 -hsync -vsync (46.6 kHz)
[    43.924] (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 684
[    43.924] (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    43.924] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   69.30  1366 1398 1430 1486  768 770 774 782 -hsync -vsync (46.6 kHz)
[    43.988] (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 684
[    43.988] (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    43.988] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1366x768"x0.0   69.30  1366 1398 1430 1486  768 770 774 782 -hsync -vsync (46.6 kHz)
[    67.375] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/event1)
[    67.376] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    67.376] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[    67.376] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    67.392] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    67.392]    compiled for 1.10.3, module version = 2.6.0
[    67.392]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    67.392]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 12.2
[    67.392] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Logitech USB Optical Mouse'
[    67.392] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    67.392] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: always reports core events
[    67.392] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[    67.392] (--) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Found 12 mouse buttons
[    67.392] (--) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Found scroll wheel(s)
[    67.392] (--) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Found relative axes
[    67.392] (--) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Found x and y relative axes
[    67.392] (II) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Configuring as mouse
[    67.392] (II) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Adding scrollwheel support
[    67.392] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    67.392] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    67.392] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/input/input14/event1"
[    67.392] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Optical Mouse" (type: MOUSE)
[    67.392] (II) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
[    67.392] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    67.392] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    67.392] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    67.392] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    67.392] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    67.392] (II) No input driver/identifier specified (ignoring)
[    78.692] (II) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Close
[    78.692] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[    78.692] (II) Unloading evdev
```

Comment: Okay, is working right now. I used aptitude to repair dependencies, which I think did the trick - we'll know for sure after I reboot the machine tomorrow.

Comment: Okay, still not working. I tried restarting udev and gdm3 - although gdm3 isn't the culprit, the system works, or doesn't, with startx too.

Answer (score 0):

Creating this xorg.conf (at etc/X11/) seems to work for me. 
Another solution might be running udevadm trigger.

```
# fix for no kbd
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option          "AutoAddDevices" "True"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier      "L0"
        InputDevice     "k0"
        InputDevice     "s0"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier      "k0"
        Driver          "evdev"
    Option "Device" "/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd" 
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier      "s0"
    Driver          "evdev"
    Option "Device" "/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-1-event-mouse" 
    Option "TapButton1" "1"
    Option "TapButton2" "0"
    Option "TapButton3" "3"
    Option "VertEdgeScroll" "on"
    Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "on"
    Option "HorizEdgeScroll" "on"
    Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "on"
    Option "CircularScrolling" "on"
    Option "CircScrollTrigger" "2"
    Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinZ" "40"
    Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinW" "8"
EndSection
```